Ruby on Rails - Failed to build libv8 16.10.0 after updating bundler version
After updating bundler version from 1.16.6 to 2.3.23, we started to get an error when running bundle install on production:
`build_libv8!': failed to build libv8 16.10.0 (Libv8::Node::BuilderError)
An error occurred while installing libv8-node (16.10.0.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
In Gemfile:
mini_racer was resolved to 0.6.3, which depends on
libv8-node


bundle platform: x86_64-linux
bundle version: 2.3.23
when we tried to lower the bundle version to previous 1.16.6, the bundle installed without errors


Looks like there was some issue with lower libv8 versions and newer bundler version.
Update of bundler to 2.4.22 and mini_racer to 0.6.4 worked, because
higher version of mini_racer (0.6.4) has higher dependency: libv8-node (~> 16.19.0.0), where the error is fixed.
Gemfile:
gem 'mini_racer', '~> 0.6.4'

Run locally before deploy:
bundle _2.4.22_ install

